# What is "celui qu’on a en avalant de travers"?

Tags: demande-de-mot

I'm reading the [french version Matilda (Henri Robillot's translation)](https://www.amazon.fr/gp/product/2070601587?pf_rd_r=DM3XENSCHZT12V3HCRAR&pf_rd_p=70373c30-7461-4a24-bb1f-f3fde4f2df3a), where there's a dialogue:

— Maintenant épelle-moi le mot « hockey ».

— Lequel ? demanda calmement Victor. Celui qu’on joue avec une crosse ou celui qu’on a en avalant de travers ?

I'm bit confused, what does this "celui qu’on a en avalant de travers" mean?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's "hiccup" (French, hoquet) ([TLFi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/hoquet)).

The description is not accurate; you get hiccups from rather unpredictable conditions ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hiccup)).

- *The hiccup is an involuntary action involving a [reflex arc](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflex_arc). Once triggered, the reflex causes a strong contraction of the diaphragm followed about a quarter of a second later by closure of the vocal cords, which results in the "hic" sound.*

"Avaler [quelque chose] de travers" means  "to swallow something that goes down the wrong way"; that does not cause hiccup, but it is understandable as the description of the cause is generally not known, something approaching has been used to refer to this phenomenon. It is quite wrong though, too much so for being useful to anyone nowadays.